# wpf know when template has changed

Tags: wpf, templates

Maybe this has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the answer through searching and googling it.   What I need is a way to tell when a template of a control has changed.  Meaning I'm looking for an event to fire when a template has changed on a control.  Something along the lines of an event called TemplateChanged.  I don't see any objects in the object hierarchy that have this event. Am I missing something here?   There must be a way to get notification of a template being changed on control.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the OnApplyTemplate() method?

Comment: For my situation I don't think this will work.  For example, I want to set focus on a particular element based on when a control's template has changed.  So I need some event to subscribe to.  If I am correct this method lets your control know internal to itself that the template has changed. I need to know external to control when its template has changed.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be:
Override OnApplyTemplate to throw some custom event. 
Subscribe to this event Externally.

be careful with handlers ;)